# how to configure hdiv with asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-applications, hdiv, websecurity

I'm working on an enterprise web project for our government but the important phase is it's security. I heard something about HDIV that secure our websites.
but I don't know how to configure/integrate it with our web application. if anyone can help I will be very thankful.
or suggest me some other **web application security frameworks** for ASP.NET MVC 5 apps.

Answer (score 0):

The integration of Hdiv within ASP .NET MVC 5 applications is done through a declarative installation. It means that your source-code remains the same and basically you have to implement the following installation steps:

1. Include Hdiv DLLs dependency within your project
2. The inclusion of a http module (web filter) within webconfig configuration file
3. Replace your PageBaseType implementation to Hdiv implementation within webconfig configuration
           file
4. Restart the application

Hdiv for .NET is distributed within Hdiv Enterprise product, particularly within Hdiv Protection product at hdivsecurity.com. Complete the web site forms to request a product demo or trial if you want to know more.

Regards,

Roberto Velasco (Hdiv Team)